# converting to OSGB36 (ruby)

Tags: ruby, maps

Im using the following code to try and convert OSGB36 To WGS84,

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Some UK Ordnance Survey coordinate conversions in pure ruby.
#
# WGS84 lat/lons -> OSGB64 lat/lons-> OS Eastings & Northings 


# http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-convert-coords.html
# (c) Chris Veness 2005-2010  Released under an LGPL license
# http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/lgpl.html
# Ported to ruby by Harry Wood


#ellipse parameters
@e = { :wgs84 =>   { :a=> 6378137,     :b=> 6356752.3142, :f=> 1 / 298.257223563 },
      :airy1830 => { :a=> 6377563.396, :b=> 6356256.910,  :f=> 1 / 299.3249646   } };

#helmert transform parameters
@h = { :wgs84toOSGB36 => { :tx=> -446.448,  :ty=>  125.157,  :tz=> -542.060,  # m
                           :rx=>  -0.1502,  :ry=>   -0.2470, :rz=>  -0.8421,  # sec
                           :s=>   20.4894 },                                  # ppm
       :osgb36toWGS84 => { :tx=>  446.448,  :ty=> -125.157,  :tz=>  542.060,
                           :rx=>    0.1502, :ry=>    0.2470, :rz=>    0.8421,
                           :s=>   -20.4894 } };


def convertOSGB36toWGS84(p1lat, p1lon, p1height) 
   p2 = convert(p1lat, p1lon, p1height, @e[:airy1830], @h[:osgb36toWGS84], @e[:wgs84]);
   return p2;
end


def convertWGS84toOSGB36(p1lat, p1lon, p1height)
   p2 = convert(p1lat, p1lon, p1height, @e[:wgs84], @h[:wgs84toOSGB36], @e[:airy1830]);
   return p2;
end

def convert(p1lat, p1lon, p1height, e1, t, e2)
   # -- convert polar to cartesian coordinates (using ellipse 1)

   p1lat = toRad(p1lat); p1lon = toRad(p1lon); 

   a = e1[:a]; b = e1[:b];

   sinPhi = Math.sin(p1lat); cosPhi = Math.cos(p1lat);
   sinLambda = Math.sin(p1lon); cosLambda = Math.cos(p1lon);
   h = p1height;

   eSq = (a*a - b*b) / (a*a);
   nu = a / Math.sqrt(1 - eSq*sinPhi*sinPhi);

   x1 = (nu+h) * cosPhi * cosLambda;
   y1 = (nu+h) * cosPhi * sinLambda;
   z1 = ((1-eSq)*nu + h) * sinPhi;


   # -- apply helmert transform using appropriate params

   tx = t[:tx]; ty = t[:ty]; tz = t[:tz];
   rx = t[:rx] / 3600 * Math::PI/180;  #normalise seconds to radians
   ry = t[:ry] / 3600 * Math::PI/180;
   rz = t[:rz] / 3600 * Math::PI/180;
   s1 = t[:s] / 1e6 + 1;              #normalise ppm to (s+1)

   #apply transform
   x2 = tx + x1*s1 - y1*rz + z1*ry;
   y2 = ty + x1*rz + y1*s1 - z1*rx;
   z2 = tz - x1*ry + y1*rx + z1*s1;


   # -- convert cartesian to polar coordinates (using ellipse 2)

   a = e2[:a]; b = e2[:b];
   precision = 4 / a;  # results accurate to around 4 metres

   eSq = (a*a - b*b) / (a*a);
   p = Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
   phi = Math.atan2(z2, p*(1-eSq)); phiP = 2 * Math::PI;
   while ( (phi-phiP).abs > precision) do
      nu = a / Math.sqrt(1 - eSq*Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(phi));
      phiP = phi;
      phi = Math.atan2(z2 + eSq*nu*Math.sin(phi), p);
   end
   lambda = Math.atan2(y2, x2);
   h = p/Math.cos(phi) - nu;

   #return array [lat,lon,height]
   return [ toDeg(phi), toDeg(lambda), h ]; 
end




# http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html
# (c) Chris Veness 2005-2010  Released under an LGPL license
# http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/lgpl.html
# Ported to ruby by Harry Wood

# OSGB36 lat lon to OS UK grid eastings & northings
def LatLongToOSGrid(lat, long)
   lat = toRad(lat);
   lon = toRad(long);

   a = 6377563.396; b = 6356256.910          # Airy 1830 major & minor semi-axes
   f0 = 0.9996012717                         # NatGrid scale factor on central meridian
   lat0 = toRad(49); lon0 = toRad(-2)        # NatGrid true origin
   n0 = -100000; e0 = 400000;                # northing & easting of true origin, metres
   e2 = 1 - (b*b) / (a*a);                   # eccentricity squared
   n = (a-b) / (a+b); n2 = n*n; n3 = n*n*n;

   cosLat = Math.cos(lat); sinLat = Math.sin(lat);
   nu = a*f0/Math.sqrt(1-e2*sinLat*sinLat);              # transverse radius of curvature
   rho = a*f0*(1-e2) / ( (1-e2*sinLat*sinLat) ** 1.5);  # meridional radius of curvature
   eta2 = nu/rho-1;

   ma = (1 + n + (5/4)*n2 + (5/4)*n3) * (lat-lat0);
   mb = (3*n + 3*n*n + (21/8)*n3) * Math.sin(lat-lat0) * Math.cos(lat+lat0);
   mc = ((15/8)*n2 + (15/8)*n3) * Math.sin(2*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(2*(lat+lat0));
   md = (35/24)*n3 * Math.sin(3*(lat-lat0)) * Math.cos(3*(lat+lat0));
   m = b * f0 * (ma - mb + mc - md);              # meridional arc

   cos3lat = cosLat*cosLat*cosLat;
   cos5lat = cos3lat*cosLat*cosLat;
   tan2lat = Math.tan(lat)*Math.tan(lat);
   tan4lat = tan2lat*tan2lat;

   i = m + n0;
   ii = (nu/2)*sinLat*cosLat;
   iii = (nu/24)*sinLat*cos3lat*(5-tan2lat+9*eta2);
   iiiA = (nu/720)*sinLat*cos5lat*(61-58*tan2lat+tan4lat);
   iv = nu*cosLat;
   v = (nu/6)*cos3lat*(nu/rho-tan2lat);
   vi = (nu/120) * cos5lat * (5 - 18*tan2lat + tan4lat + 14*eta2 - 58*tan2lat*eta2);

   dLon = lon-lon0;
   dLon2 = dLon*dLon
   dLon3 = dLon2*dLon
   dLon4 = dLon3*dLon
   dLon5 = dLon4*dLon
   dLon6 = dLon5*dLon

   n = i + ii*dLon2 + iii*dLon4 + iiiA*dLon6;
   e = e0 + iv*dLon + v*dLon3 + vi*dLon5;

   return [ e, n ]   #return raw easting and northings instead

   #return gridrefNumToLet( e, n, 8) 
end

def toRad(degrees)
   return degrees * Math::PI / 180;
end

def toDeg(rads)
   return rads * 180 / Math::PI 
end

#convert numeric grid reference (in metres) to standard-form grid ref
def gridrefNumToLet(e, n, digits) 
   #get the 100km-grid indices
   e100k = (e / 100000).floor; n100k = (n / 100000).floor;

   return '' if (e100k<0 or e100k>6 or n100k<0 or n100k>12)

   #translate those into numeric equivalents of the grid letters
   l1 = (19-n100k) - (19-n100k) % 5 + ((e100k+10) / 5).floor;
   l2 = (19-n100k) * 5 % 25 + e100k % 5;

   # compensate for skipped 'I' and build grid letter-pairs         
   l1=l1+1 if (l1 > 7)
   l2=l2+1 if (l2 > 7) 
   letPair =  (l1 +'A'[0]).chr +  (l2 +'A'[0]).chr ;

   # strip 100km-grid indices from easting & northing, and reduce precision
   e = ( (e % 100000) / (10 ** (5 - digits / 2)) ).floor;
   n = ( (n % 100000) / (10 ** (5 - digits / 2)) ).floor;

   gridRef = letPair + e.to_s.rjust(digits / 2) + n.to_s.rjust(digits / 2)

   return gridRef;
end


# Example WGS84 lat/lon to convert
lon = -0.10322
lat = 51.52237
height = 0

osgb36point = convertWGS84toOSGB36(lat,lon, height)
oslat = osgb36point[0]
oslon = osgb36point[1]
osh = osgb36point[2]

osUKgridPoint = LatLongToOSGrid(oslat,oslon)
easting  = osUKgridPoint[0].round
northing = osUKgridPoint[1].round

gridrefLetters = gridrefNumToLet(easting,northing, 8)

puts "wgs84 lat:" + lat.to_s + ", wgs84 lon:" + lon.to_s
puts "http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=" + lat.to_s + "&mlon=" + lon.to_s + "&zoom=16"
puts "Converts to:";
puts "osgb36 lat:" + oslat.to_s + ", osgb36 lon:" + oslon.to_s
puts "Converts to:";
puts "easting:" + easting.to_s + ", northing:" + northing.to_s + "  As a grid ref:" + gridrefLetters
puts "http://streetmap.co.uk/grid/" + easting.to_s + "_" + northing.to_s + "_106"
```

i can't seem to get it working, can someone give me an example method using the OSGB36toWGS84 method. It does run (on the one i edited), however the output is incorrect.

my code:

```
lon =  521490
lat =  192263
height = 0

osgb36point = convertOSGB36toWGS84(lat,lon, height)
oslat = osgb36point[0]
oslon = osgb36point[1]
osh = osgb36point[2]

osUKgridPoint = LatLongToOSGrid(oslat,oslon)
easting  = osUKgridPoint[0].round
northing = osUKgridPoint[1].round
```

output:

```
wgs84 lat:192263, wgs84 lon:521490
Converts to:
osgb36 lat:23.00619802206627, osgb36 lon:-149.99650128215052
Converts to:
easting:-33856949, northing:56599846
```

below is the blog entry (see pure ruby implementation section)
http://www.harrywood.co.uk/blog/category/maps/page/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide YOUR code - including your input parameters and the (incorrect) output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Tes9LAet - Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

From the blog post, it looks like you are working with geodata which doesn't change (the locations of the tube lines), so it seems like it would make more sense to do the conversion once, ahead of time, instead of on-the-fly.  This means that you could use ogr2ogr and avoid coding a conversion routine altogether:
   http://www.mercatorgeosystems.com/blog-articles/2008/05/30/using-ogr2ogr-to-re-project-a-shape-file/